# How to dectect every layer in the View OpenLayers3

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm trying to detect all the layers seen in the view of the map (OpenLayers 3).
I've tried this method but it works just for a pixel.

```
map.forEachLayerAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(layer){ 
       // And I edit the layer...
    });
```

Is there any function that allow me to do it?

thanks.

Comment: see: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123234/get-single-layer-in-openlayers-3

Comment: doesn't work for me...because in this example I get all the layers in the map. but in my case I want just the layers seen by the user in the map View.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to loop through the layers and check if the extent intersects with the view extent.  That will at least get you the layers that have some pixels within the current view.

```
var viewExtent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
var layersInView = [];
map.getLayers().forEach(function (layer) {
  var layerExtent = layer.getExtent();

  if (ol.extent.intersects(layerExtent, viewExtent)) {
    layersInView.push(layer);
  }
});
```

I'm not sure how you'd tell if a layer is *actually* visible to the user, but this might get you closer.

Comment: the `getExtent()` doesn't work for me so I had to replace it with `layer.getSource().c.extent; ` your solution works fine if the layer source is   `ol.source.ImageStatic`  but if it's a WMS layer it doesn't work. thanks